# His Hands Were Tied

Tags: phrase-meaning

Could you see whose hands are tied? Trump's or McConnell's?

> McConnell, Denouncing Trump After Voting to Acquit, Says **His Hands Were Tied**
>
> The top Senate Republican gave his most damning condemnation of Donald Trump, but said the Senate had no power to convict an ex-president. He had refused to try Mr. Trump while he remained in office.

Source:  [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/02/13/us/mcconnell-trump-impeachment-acquittal.html)

Comment: This seems to be a case of a misplaced phrase... to be more clear, it should read, "McConnell Says His Hands Were Tied, Denouncing Trump After Voting to Acquit".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Senate had no power to convict an ex-president, this fact would tie the hands of (=prevent action by) people in the Senate, like McConnell, but not people outside the Senate, like Trump. So it must be McConnell with his hands tied.